Cardinality of set of convergent series with countably infinite indexed terms
Let $l(\mathbb{N})$ be the set of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \vert a_n \vert
$ converges, where $a_n\in \mathbb{R}$.
My question is what is the cardinality of $l(\mathbb{N})$? And a follow up would be if the choice of the normed vector space for the terms in the sequence changes the answer?
My intuition says that if we take the CH to be true then $\lvert l(\mathbb{N})\rvert\cong \lvert \mathbb{R}\rvert$ but I’m not sure what happens otherwise.
For the follow up, I don’t think a different finite dimensional vector space would change things, but again my intuition might be failing me.

Why is there a subscript $n$ in the notation $I_n(\Bbb N)$?

should have just been a 1, but ill remove it altogether for clarity

There are $#\Bbb R$ choices for $a_1$ with all other terms $0$, and at most $#(\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}) = #\Bbb R$ series (convergent or not) ... doesn't this answer the question already?

what about if CH is false?

A bijection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ can be constructed without CH. Just use a bijection $\mathbb{R} \to 2^{\mathbb{N}}$.

@GregMartin Yes that's an answer (and should be posted as such).

without CH there is no bijection $\mathbb{R}\to 2^{\mathbb{N}}$

@MattanFeldman That assertion is false. A bijection $\mathbb{R}\to 2^{\mathbb{N}}$ can be constructed in $\mathsf{ZF}$. What $\mathsf{CH}$ asserts is that there is no set $X$ such that $\mathbb{N}$ embeds into $X$ but is not bijectable with $X$, and $X$ embeds into $\mathbb{R}$ but is not bijectable with $\mathbb{R}$. That is, that there is no set $X$ with $#\mathbb{N}\lt #X \lt #\mathbb{R}$. That is not about bijecting $\mathbb{R}$ with $2^{\mathbb{N}}$.

in Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory with the axiom of choice (ZFC), this is equivalent to the following equation in aleph numbers:
$2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ (from wikipedia) am i misunderstanding something?

So what? We know that $\mathbb{R}$ can be bijected with $2^{\mathbb{N}}$. The Continuum Hypothesis has nothing to do with that. Nobody is saying this cardinal is $\aleph_1$, we are saying the cardinal is $2^{\aleph_0}$, whatever that aleph number this happens to be.

Makes more sense, thank you!

The Continuum Hypothesis has nothing to do with this.
It is a theorem of $\mathsf{ZF}$ that $\mathbb{R}$ can be bijected with $2^{\mathbb{N}}$. There are multiple ways of doing this, but here is one:
First, we can define a one-to-one function from $[0,1)$ to $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ by writing the numbers in $[0,1)$ in binary expansion without tails of $1$s, and mapping the number $x$ to the subset of indices for which the expansion is equal to $1$.
Second, we can define a one-to-one function from $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ to $[0,1)$, by mapping the subset $S$ to the number which, in decimal notation, has a $5$ in position $n$ if $n\in S$ and has a $6$ in position $n$ if $n\notin S$.
Third, we can invoke Cantor-Bernstein (which is a theorem of $\mathsf{ZF}$ which states that if we have sets $A$ and $B$, and we have one-to-one functions $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to A$, then there exists a bijection $h\colon A\to B$) to conclude that that $[0,1)$ is bijectable with $2^{\mathbb{N}}$.
Fourth, we can biject $[0,1)$ with $(0,1)$: map $0$ to $\frac{1}{2}$, map $\frac{1}{2^k}$ to $\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$ for each natural number $k$, and send every other element of $[0,1)$ to itself.
Fifth, we can biject $(0,1)$ with $\mathbb{R}$. For example, the map $$x\longmapsto \frac{1}{\pi}\left(\arctan(x)+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
is such a bijection.
Thus, we can biject $\mathbb{R}$ with $2^{\mathbb{N}}$, and this is a theorem of $\mathsf{ZF}$.
Now, it is clear that the set of convergent sequences is contained in the set of all sequences, which is $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$. This has cardinality
$$\left|\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}\right| = |\mathbb{R}|^{|\mathbb{N}|} = (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}.$$
(All of those computations are true in $\mathsf{ZF}$.)
On the other hand, $\mathbb{R}$ can be embedded into the set of convergent sequences via the map
$$r\longmapsto (r,0,0,0,0,0,\ldots),$$
so we have embeddings from $\mathbb{R}$ into the set $\ell(\mathbb{N})$, and from the set $\ell(\mathbb{N})$ into $\mathbb{R}$, so again by Cantor-Bernstein we conclude that
$$|\ell(\mathbb{N})| = |\mathbb{R}| = 2^{\aleph_0},$$
and this equality holds in $\mathsf{ZF}$, regardless of $\mathsf{CH}$.

And the choice of vector space would only change the use of $\mathbb{R}$ everywhere which wouldn’t impact the result as long as the vector space is finite dimentional, right?

@MattanFeldman Vector space over what? A finite dimensional vector space with scalars from a field $F$ such that $|F|\leq|\mathbb{R}|$, same thing, because if $2\leq |X|\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$, then $|X^{\mathbb{N}}|=2^{\aleph_0}$, since $$2^{\aleph_0}\leq |X|^{\aleph_0}\leq (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0},$$ and again Cantor-Bernstein gives you the desired equality. But if you have a field with strictly larger cardinality than $\mathbb{R}$, then you'll get a larger cardinal (or in the absence of $\mathsf{AC}$, if your field is incomparable with $\mathbb{R}$, then things get hairy)
